# in scala how to convert the result in sql query row to double

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I try to get the result of spark sql query and do some calculations for them in Scala.

```
 val sql_DF = spark.sql("SELECT count(distinct(my_id)) total_id FROM some_ids_table ")

 val total_ids = sql_DF.select("total_id").first().toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]][0]


 val sql_DF01 = spark.sql("SELECT count(distinct(other_id)) other_ids FROM some_ids_table where column_value1 = 1")

 val  other_id_1 = sql_DF01.select("other_ids").first().toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]][0]

 println(other_id_1/total_ids)
```

I got error:

```
 error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
 val total_ids = sql_DF.select("total_id").first().toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]][0]
```

How to convert the result in sql query row to double so that I can do some math calculations on them?
e.g.

```
   other_ids / total_ids
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CAST function as below

```
scala>  val sql_DF = spark.sql("SELECT count(distinct(eid)) total_id FROM employee ")
sql_DF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [total_id: bigint]
```

Using the CAST function the bigint is converted to double

```
scala>  val sql_DF = spark.sql("SELECT CAST(count(distinct(eid)) AS DOUBLE) total_id FROM employee ")
sql_DF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [total_id: double]
```

Comment: I got the error: the "/" in "other_id_1/total_ids" is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
var tmp = round_up(other_id_1/other_id) * 100. It seems that the value of "other_id_1" is still in the format of a row in the sql query result rather than a number.

Comment: Can you print the schema ? Why do you have a column of type Row ?

Answer (score 0):

The question didn't seem quite clear to me. Here's how you generally handle the situation below.

`import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("a",90.0),("b",30.0)).toDF("name","marks")`

> Collect the data in column "marks", which will be of type'Array[Row]'

`val rows: Array[Row] = df.select("marks").collect()`

> You specifically need to get each element using map and give it the type as per its datatype in the column.

`val values: Array[Double] = rows.map(row => row.getAs[Double](0)/*row.getDouble(0)*/)`

Answer (score 0):

There are different points in your question. If you want to get the count of distinct 'my_id' and assign it to a value, you can do it directly with:

```
total_ids = sql_DF.dropDuplicates("my_id").count()
```

The error that you are getting is due to the way to access the data from DF (You need to access to row object: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html).

Alternative: You can directly cast your DF using `.as[DataType]`, like this:

```
val total_id = sql_DF.selectExpr("count(distinct(my_id)) as total_id").as[Long].first()
```

Comment: I follow up https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html), but, I got error: value / is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double] . whenI try to do division for numerator and denominator, both of which are RDD[Double]

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet for it? Basically, you need to extract first the value, depending on the type that you have in your `DF`. Something like this:

`val numerator = sql_DF.selectExpr("count(distinct(my_id)) as total_id").as[Long].first()`

`val denominator = another_DF.selectExpr("count(distinct(my_id)) as total_id").as[Long].first()`

`val res = numerator.toDouble / denominator.toDouble`

Where, you first get `numerator` and `denominator`, then performs the operation.